# C# How to print a list containing textbox and numbericupdown value?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am working on this project and am stuck.

I am trying to print a list containing textbox text and numbericupdown values.
This is my class

```
class Animal
    {
        public string Species{ get; set; }
        public int Size{ get; set; }
        public string Eater{get; set;}

        public Dier(string species, int size, string eater)
        {
            this.Species= species;
            this.Size= size;
            this.Eater= eater;
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Hoofd()
            {
                Animal animal1= new Animal("Panda", 3, "Herbivore");
                Console.WriteLine("animal1 Species = {0} Size = {1} Eater = {2}", animal1.Species, animal1.Size, animal1.Eater);

            }
}
}
```

The output of this code is what I am trying to achieve.

So I have 2 textboxes and 1 numericupdown.
I want to store this information in a animal2 list like this:

```
int numericUpDownChangeToInt = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
Animal animal2 = new Animal(textBox1.Text, numericUpDownChangeToInt, textBox2.Text);
Console.WriteLine(animal2);
```

And print this information to the console output,

The result that I am getting is: Animalproject.Animal

The result that I would like to get is the input of the textboxes and the numericupdown.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to access the properties of the `Animal` class in order to print out the values. See below code.

```
int numericUpDownChangeToInt = 2; //Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
Animal animal2 = new Animal("Textbox1", numericUpDownChangeToInt, "Textbox2");
Console.WriteLine("Species: "+  animal2.Species + "\nSize: "+  animal2.Size.ToString() + "\nEater: "+  animal2.Eater);
```